# Angular 2 (typescript) as a Service Provider for SAML2 authentication

Tags: android, angularjs, authentication, ionic2, saml-2.0

I have created a application on angular2 (typescript) and am using ionic to generate apk file.

Now I would like to integrate SAML2 for authentication.
I already have a Identity provider Metadata.

Now few things that I am stuck with-

1. How can I generate the SP Metadata for my angular2 app.
2. How can I make my angular2 app behave as a service provider.
3. How to read Identity Provider Metadata from my angular2 app
4. What all SAML2 apis can I use for my angular2 app.

I am completely new to SAML and angular2. Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks for the guidance :)

Comment: did you find some solutions which integrate SAML with angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

SAML was not designed with client-side JavaScript in mind. I think the most viable solution would be to use a backend that can do the SAML-handling, and then use JWT "bearer tokens" to authenticate your JavaScript-calls to your backend.